# How to iterate over a list of values in a dict using jinja?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a dict with a list of values, basically each key has 10 values:

```py
movies = {
'title': ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', ..., 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring'],
'year': ['1994', '1972', ..., '2001'],
'poster': ['url', 'url1', ..., 'url9'],
'rating': ['9.2', '9.1', ..., '8.8'],
'votes': ['2467733', '1705796', ..., '1732916']
}
```

I'm using them to dinamicaly generate cards in HTML so I need every card to have one value of each key. Ultimately I'll end up with 10 cards. Here's my HTML and my latest attempt to iterate the dict with jinja:

```html
{% for movie in movies %}
    {% for key, value in movie.items() %} <!-- This line is raising an error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items' -->
        {% for value in key %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                    <img src="{{ value.poster }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Movie Poster">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">{{ value.title }}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Release year: {{ value.year }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">Rating: {{ value.rating }} - ({{ value.votes }} Votes)</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                     <a href="#" class="card-link">More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

What is the Jinja sintax to do it?

Comment: how do you send data to template ? It seems you converted it to string and now you have string instead of dictionary.

Comment: you have too many `for`-loops. You should use `.items()` in first loop with `movies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not syntax but your data - you organized data in wrong way.
And then all your `for`-loops makes no sense.

You have one dictionary with many lists but you should have one list with many dictionaries.

```
movies = [
    {
        'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption',
        'year': '1994',
        'poster': 'url',
        'rating': '9.2',
        'votes': '2467733'
    },
    {
        'title': 'The Godfather',
        'year': '1972',
        'poster': 'url1',
        'rating': '9.1',
        'votes': '1705796', 
    },
    # ... other movies ...
]
```

and then you can use your

```
{% for movie in movies %}
     {{ movie.poster }}
     {{ movie.title }}
     {{ movie.year }}
     {{ movie.rating }} - ({{ movie.votes }}
```

---

With original data you use `for`-loops in wrong way. First `for`-loop `{% for movie in movies %}` works like `{% for key in movies.keys() %}` and  you get string `"title"` and you try to use it with next `for`-loop - and this makes your problem. You would have to use `index` like `movies.title[n]` with `for n in range(movies.title|length))`.

```
{% for n in range(movies.title|length)) %}
     {{ movies.poster[n] }}
     {{ movies.title[n] }}
     {{ movies.year[n] }}
     {{ movies.rating[n] }} - ({{ movies.votes[n] }}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code with both versions.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    movies = [
        {
            'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption',
            'year': '1994',
            'poster': 'url',
            'rating': '9.2',
            'votes': '2467733'
        },
        {
            'title': 'The Godfather',
            'year': '1972',
            'poster': 'url1',
            'rating': '9.1',
            'votes': '1705796', 
        },
        # ... other movies ...
    ]

    return render_template_string('''
{% for movie in movies %}
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{{ movie.poster }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Movie Poster">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ movie.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Release year: {{ movie.year }}</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Rating: {{ movie.rating }} - ({{ movie.votes }} Votes)</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body">
         <a href="#" class="card-link">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
''', movies=movies)


@app.route('/version2')
def version2():
    
    movies = {
        'title': ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', ..., 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring'],
        'year': ['1994', '1972', ..., '2001'],
        'poster': ['url', 'url1', ..., 'url9'],
        'rating': ['9.2', '9.1', ..., '8.8'],
        'votes': ['2467733', '1705796', ..., '1732916']
    }

    return render_template_string('''
{% for n in range(movies.title|length) %}
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{{ movies.poster[n] }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Movie Poster">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ movies.title[n] }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Release year: {{ movies.year[n] }}</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Rating: {{ movies.rating[n] }} - ({{ movies.votes[n] }} Votes)</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body">
         <a href="#" class="card-link">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
''', movies=movies)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Comment: I actually receive my data as a list of dictionaries, but when iterating over them I only received on movie. That's why I changed to one dictionary with lists; I thought would be easier to work with this format, but it wasn't. Although is good to know that is possible to work with both formats, I'll try them and see which one suits me best.